# cannot edit permission for a folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

I am using Windows Server 2008 x64. I login using administrator. I want to add a new user for read/write access for a folder under c:\windows\system32. I tried to select folder (right click), then select Property -> Security -> Edit under Security Tab, the Add button is greyed out. Why?

I tried the same operation under other non-windows system folder, it is ok to add new user to permission.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing permissions of a system folder is not a very good idea. Maybe you are not the owner of the folder, you can try to take ownership of the folder, but this could lead to system malfunctions.

Comment: Any ideas to add read/write permission to a system folder? I have special needs for my specific application.

Comment: Question answered.

Comment: This is one of my main gripes about Windows. Why doesn't the administrator account have full access to all operating system areas? Who's controlling the system here: is there a special Bill Gates root account?